# Work Flow of HashMap

Tags: java

I have added 2 objects in hash map but keys of 2 values are same. even implemented hashcode and equals method. but still it is showing 2 values instead of 3.

code:

```
package test1;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapDemo {

    int i;
    String abc;
    HashMapDemo(int a,String b){
        i=a;
        abc=b;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return i +abc;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashMapDemo obj1= new HashMapDemo(2,"hello");
        HashMapDemo obj2= new HashMapDemo(3,"world");
        HashMapDemo obj3= new HashMapDemo(4,"around");
        toDos t1=new toDos("aa");
        toDos t2=new toDos("bb");
        toDos t3=new toDos("aa");
        HashMap test=new HashMap();
        test.put(t1,obj1);
        test.put(t2, obj2);
        test.put(t3,obj3);
        System.out.println(test.size()+""+test.get(obj2)+test);

    }
}
```

Code for keys:

```
package test1;

import java.util.HashMap;

class toDos
 {

        String a;
    toDos(String b){
        a=b;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        System.out.println("call of equals");
        if((toDos)obj instanceof toDos & (toDos)obj !=null){
            toDos temp = (toDos) obj;
            if(temp.a.equals(this.a)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    public int hashCode(){
        System.out.println("call of hasCode");
        return (a!=null)? a.hashCode():0;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return a;
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can't *have* "keys of 2 values are same". Keys are *unique* in a HashMap.

Comment: Do `System.out.println(test.put(t3,obj3))` . HashMap put will return the previous value associated with the key

Answer (score 1):

According to your equals method of `class toDos` if `String a` is same then both object are same.

```
HashMap test=new HashMap();
test.put(t1,obj1); // "aa"
test.put(t2,obj2); // "bb"
test.put(t3,obj3); //"aa"
```

So both Obj1 and obj2 would be treated as same object so your old value obj1 will be replaced with obj3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `t1.equals(t3)` - and thus, the insertion  of `t3` overrides the first inserted entry.

In a `HashMap`, each distinct key has one associated value - and since `t1` and `t3` equals each other - you have only 2 distinct keys.

As a side note - you should avoid using [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) and use the [generics types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) as much as possible.